# how to create drag and drop widget using mouse listener in Google web toolkit

Tags: gwt

I am new in Google web toolkit.i want to create example of drag and drop using mouse listener in Google web toolkit.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what approach you wanted to use.

1.- GWT core supports drag-and-drop from the version 2.4. It works well but is not a complete implementation. This [post](http://jamies-gwt.blogspot.ca/2012/11/gwt24-drag-drop-in-tree.html) has a good example of how to use it.

2.- [gwt-dnd](https://code.google.com/p/gwt-dnd/wiki/GettingStarted) is a classical library in the GWT world which it makes things pretty easier.

3.- Finally you have a [gwtQuery](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/) plugin ([gquery drag-and-drop](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery-plugins/wiki/DragAndDropPluginForGWTDeveloppers)) supporting touch events, etc.

Normally I'd rather use #3 because is simpler, works better and supports more features.

Comment: can i create using mouse listener?

Comment: Yes, you can use the generic method `widget.addDomHandler`, in the first link I sent you have some examples.